# Any way of having fragments on a slide automatically appear without any clicks?

Tags: reveal.js

Just started using reveal.js, and it's awesome.

I understand there is a way of making slides transition automatically and fragments as well, but from the README it seems to me that fragments can transition only when slides are set to automatically switch forwards.

I want the control to be only for slides, and have fragments appear automatically with either per slide timing for the fragments or alternatively global timing, but for fragments only.

Hope someone here has an idea.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fragments support the data-autoslide as well. you will need to add

```
 data-autoslide="0"
```

on your last fragment, so it doesn't automatically move you to the next slide.

then you remove default controls, and add your own control with

```
class="navigate-next"
```

that class will navigate the user to next slide, instead that to the next fragment

see https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#internal-links